How did the other families avoid paying Verna's price?
In 2023 series The Fall of the House of Usher, the mysterious figure, Verna, is mentioned as having been around various historical families, with the heavy implication that a deal with her was responsible for their success. These are families who in real life, while they may have experienced the occasional tragedy, by and large did not suffer the total familial annihilation through contrived accidents and suicide over the course of a few weeks that afflicted the House of Usher; indeed, in real life, many of them died at an old age, kept their money and (more or less) reputation, and have living descendants.1
However, Verna intimates that Roderick killing himself would not have prevented her from exacting her price, although she does seem to give the Usher children a bit of a warning before they died, even suggesting that they could have been killed quietly in their beds. Still, it did not seem as if she meant "years after, from old age." Of course, it's possible that this is an element of the alternate history of the series, and that unlike in the real world, those families experienced something like the fall of the Ushers.
How, if at all, did some of the historical families mentioned avoid the fate of the Ushers?

1: One example would be Prescott Bush, mentioned on the show; in real life, he, his wife, and his children all died old over the course of many years in non-horrible ways, and their family retains money and prestige in certain political circles.
